# Bootstrap css is not working when I used .htaccess to redirect all

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess

Now route problem is solved. `bootstrap` `css` not working..here is `.htaccess` code.
`htaccess` is in root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]` and try again?

Comment: not working yet @davidev

Comment: Is there any suggestion bro? @davidev

Comment: Try to use full path where you include your css file. No relative

Comment: here is css link <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path where you include your css files.

This might be with your url, or just absolute from server root.

`<style rel="stylesheet" href="https://yoururl.com/css/bootstrap.css">`

Another option is to use `<base href="/" />`, so that every relative path is rerouted to that origin.

Comment: Nothing Change bro.. @davidev

Answer (score 0):

Modify your .htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*js)(?!.*css)(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```